# How to denote a set of all points that satisfy equation in Cartesian plane?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, coordinate-systems

How can I denote a set of all points that satisfy $y=7-3x$ equation? Do you denote this set in set-builder?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\ |\ y=7-3x\}$

Comment: A set of points must be ordered pairs. $\mathbb R^2$ is the cartesian plane